# Custom rest_framework authentication not getting called

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am using djangorestframework 3.9.2

I have following setting for rest_framework

```
....
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'my_project.middlewares.authentication.CentralAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'my_project.middlewares.authorization.CentralAuthorization'
    ],
}
....
```

And my directory structure is this

```
├── app1/
└── my_project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── middlewares
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── authentication.py
    │   └── authorization.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── commons.py
    │   ├── development.py
    │   └── logger.py
    ├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

My authentication script is not getting call whenever I access my URL.

Is there something I am missing over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These permission classes or authentication classes are ***not middlewares*** and it will not get executed automatically. These classes are works only with **DRF views**

So, define a DRF view and wire-up the view in your `urls.py` module

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class FooAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'message': 'success'})


urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', FooAPI.as_view(), name='foo-api'),

]
```

During the execution of this **`FooAPI`** class, the DRF will call the default `permission_classes` and `authentication_classes`